# Pass a buffer of chars from .NET to COM and get it back updated

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

I have the following COM method to be called from C#, which returns a string in the provided buffer `pchText` (which is **not** necessarily zero terminated) and the number of characters copied in `pcch`:

```
HRESULT Next([in, out] long* pcch, [out, size_is(*pcch)] OLECHAR* pchText);
```

How do I define the C# signature for interop?

So far, I tried this:

```
void Next(ref int pcch,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeParamIndex = 0)]
    System.Text.StringBuilder pchText);
```

It appears to work, but I am not sure if `SizeParamIndex` has any effect on `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Is this a method you defined or something you have to use?

Comment: @PauloMadeira, the COM method signature is something I have to use. I do have my own mock of that COM object, for unit testing. But now I use `char[] pchText` in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25039290/2674222

Comment: That's quite unfortunate, a more reliable and remotable signature would be `HRESULT Next([in] cch, [out] long* pcch, [out, size_is(cch), length_is(*pcch)] OLECHAR* pchText);`.  What interface/object has this method?

Comment: @PauloMadeira, this is a DLL COM library which is supplied by a 3rd party vendor. It is only used in-process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it certainly is a difficult function to call correctly.  Your declaration is roughly okay, you just need to apply the [PreserveSig] attribute and make the return value type *int* so you can discover an S_FALSE return value that indicates there is no next element.

The difficulty is in having to guess up front how large the StringBuilder to pass.  The native code gets a raw pointer into the GC heap, pointing to the builder buffer, so accidents are pretty fatal.  You must guess up front at a proper Capacity for the builder and pass that as the initial *pcch* argument.

The marshaller *does* pay attention to the SizeParamIndex after the function returns.  It will only copy as many characters as *ppch* indicates.  If it for any reason it writes more than can fit in the buffer then the program will instantly abort with an ExecutionEngineException since that indicates that the GC heap was corrupted.

Do beware that if you guess at a Capacity that is too low then you can't necessarily discover this.  You might just get a truncated string when the function copies only as many characters that fit and doesn't return an error code.  Best way to find out if that's a problem is by just testing this and intentionally passing a small builder.  Pay attention to the return value.

One quirk is worth pointing out, the function signature hits at a hack that was common in the early days of COM, actually returning binary data instead of text through the OLECHAR*.  Strong hint that's the case since the string isn't guaranteed to be zero-terminated.  This will not come to a good end in .NET, the data will get corrupted when the string is normalized.  And crash your program when data happens to match one of the utf-16 surrogate characters.  If that's the case then you need a short[] instead of a StringBuilder.

Comment: Thank you, a good point about possible multiple `\0x0` chars in the buffer. Could I use a signature like this `[PreserveSig] int Next(ref int pcch, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)], char[] pchText)`? Is there any principal difference between `char[]` and `short[]`, for this matter?

Comment: If it is actually binary data then using *char* is not sensible.  The pinvoke marshaller will also assume 8-bit ansi characters, that's a mismatch with OLECHAR.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to create some c++/CLI wrappers in their own small project that to guess at how to marshal this?