# Does .NET interop copy array data back and forth, or does it pin the array?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com, com-interop

I have this COM method signature, declared in C#:

```
void Next(ref int pcch,
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)]
          char[] pchText);
```

I call it like this:

```
int cch = 100;
var buff = new char[cch];
com.Next(ref cch, buff);
```

Does the .NET interop layer first copy the whole array to a temporary unmanaged memory buffer, then copy it back? Or does the array get automatically pinned and passed by reference?

For the sake of trying, I did this in the COM object (C++):

```
*pcch = 1;
pchText[0] = L'A';
pchText[1] = L'\x38F'; // 'Ώ'
```

I do get `'Ώ'` back when I check `buff[1]` in C# upon return. But I don't think this is a strong proof that the array gets pinned, rather than copied back and forth.

Comment: This does not answer the question as how this is all exactly implemented, but the pchText parameter is implicitely an In parameter in this case. It just happens to work because you're in-process (and it's probably implemented just as a pointer). Try with an out-of-process COM server and it will not work (and your C++ code will be just messing with the stub memory in the process). You need to add some ref or out to it if it's really an out or ref parameter.

Comment: @SimonMourier, sorry I didn't clarify this, but it is just an in-process DLL COM object, no proxies/stubs.

Comment: Every COM interface is supposed to work in or out of process

Comment: @SimonMourier, I agree, what I meant is that in our project it is only used in-process on STA thread. Regardless, I followed your advice and added `[In, Out]`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25039290/2674222.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's do a small experiment. First, let's change your COM method to look like this (in C++):

```cpp
STDMETHODIMP CComObject::Next(ULONG* pcch, int* addr, OLECHAR* pbuff)
{
    pbuff[0] = L'A';
    pbuff[1] = L'\x38F';
    *addr = (int)pbuff;
    *pcch = 1;
    return S_OK;
}
```

Then, change the C# method signature:

```
void Next(ref uint pcch, out IntPtr addr, 
    [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)]
    char[] pbuff);
```

Finally, test it like this:

```
uint cch = 10;
var buff = new char[cch];
IntPtr addr1;

unsafe
{
    fixed (char* p = &buff[0])
    {
        addr1 = (IntPtr)p;
    }
}

IntPtr addr2;
com.Next(ref cch, out addr2, buff);
Console.WriteLine(addr1 == addr2);
```

As expected, `addr1 == addr2` is `true`. Thus, apparently the array does get pinned rather than copied when passed to COM.

That said, I couldn't find any documentation which would feature this as a hard requirement for a CLR implementation. E.g., this may or may not be true for Mono.

Comment: This is somewhat documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23acw07k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I can't replicate this, the addresses are different.  EDIT: I can replicate in the same apartment.  But, whether in the same apartment or not, the data doesn't appear to be written to the `char[]`.

Comment: I found out why, I was using (in terms of IDL) `[out] LPWSTR *pszData`, for which I'm `CoTaskMemAlloc`ing.  That memory address was being written instead of the actual characters.

Comment: @PauloMadeira, my answer assumes the same COM apartment. Inter-thread and inter-process COM marshaling is much more complex, but at least the .NET-to-COM interop part doesn't create an intermediate buffer (in the above code). Then, COM marshaller may be creating one, but it has no idea it deals with a .NET object, either.

Answer (score 9):

It isn't always easy to tell, particularly if you use an invalid declaration of course.  A char[] can't be marshaled as LPWStr, it has to be LPArray.  Now the CharSet attribute plays a role, since you did not specify it, the char[] will be marshaled as an 8-bit char[], not a 16-bit wchar_t[].  The marshaled array element is not the same size (it is not "blittable") so the marshaller *must* copy the array.

Pretty undesirable, particularly given that your C++ code expects wchar_t.  A very easy way to tell in this specific case is not getting anything back in the array.  If the array is marshaled by copying then you have to tell the marshaller explicitly that the array needs to be copied back after the call.  You'd have to apply the `[In, Out]` attribute on the argument.  You'll get Chinese.

The normal way to tell if the array gets marshaled by copying is by using the debugger.  Enable unmanaged debugging in your C# program.  Set a breakpoint on the call as well as a breakpoint in the first statement in the native function.  When the 1st breakpoint hits, use Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory 1.  Put *buff* in the Address box and switch the display to "4-byte Integer".  You'll see the address of the array object, the 4-byte type handle, the 4-byte array length and the array content itself.  So you know that if the array isn't copied that the passed addressed is the displayed address plus 8.

Press F5 to continue, the breakpoint in the native function hits.  Look at the *pchText* argument, the debugger tells you its address.  If it matches then the marshaller simply passed a pointer.  If not then you got a copy of the array.

Comment: Hmmm, the problem with CharSet is that it is applied to the whole function, not an individual parameter.  And it doesn't affect `char[]` anyway, but string parameters specified as `LPTStr`.  The right way to implement a string buffer is with `StringBuilder`... you can preallocate it to the desired size, and also specify either `LPStr` or `LPWStr`.

Comment: Hans, thank again, it is actually an `LPArray`, I just blindly copied the old code from the [answer we've met before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980511/pass-a-buffer-of-chars-from-net-to-com-and-get-it-back-updated).

Comment: Actually, `char` works great. I think `CharSet` matters for `p/invoke` but not for COM (as we also discussed before). E.g., I tried `Ώ` (`pchText[0] = L'\x38F'`) and it makes its way back to C#.