# Does MarshalAs result in an array copy?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a project that handles considerably large arrays. Some of the code is written in C, and some of it is written in C#. To pass data from C to C#, I am using the `MarshalAs` attribute. Since the arrays are large, I would rather avoid copying. So my question is: Will `MarshalAs` cause the data to be copied from C to C#, or will the C# `byte[]` refer to the exact same location that was allocated by C?

A C function is responsible for passing the data to C#, which means I use a callback. The callback looks like this:

```
void (*to_call)(const uint8_t* buffer, int buffer_length);

DLLEXPORT
init(void(*callback)(const uint8_t* buffer, int buffer_length))
{
    to_call = callback;
}
```

Eventually, the `to_call` callback will be called from C. The C# code looks like this:

```
public delegate void Callback([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]byte[] buffer, int bufferLength);

[DllImport(DLLPath)]
public static extern void init(Callback callback);
```

I would also like to know how the answer applies to .Net Framework and .Net Core.

Comment: I don't have my copy of Adam Nathan's ".NET and COM" book handy, but if I remember correctly, _"It depends"_.  Again, if I can remember (from about a decade ago), it depends on whether the two representations are _isotropic_ (i.e, they fit in the same bits in the same way).  When going from a .NET `byte[]` to unmanaged code it may work.  The opposite direction will (I'm pretty sure) not work.  .NET Arrays are managed objects laid out in a particular fashion.  I'm about 99% sure that you can't build a `byte[]` from an unmanaged collection of bytes.  The new `Span` feature may help??

Comment: You can avoid copies by allocating all of your structures in managed memory (C#), pinning them and passing the pointers to your unmanaged code. Rick Brewster did [a good write-up (with code)](https://blog.getpaint.net/2012/04/30/marshaling-native-arrays-back-as-managed-arrays-without-copying/) detailing how he did this in paint.net; also [see this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/copying-and-pinning) Other than that, you might also want to look into [Memory Mapped files](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/06/23/memory-mapped-files.aspx).

Comment: Are you going to use these arrays in C# or just pass them around? If you just pass them around, you can use IntPtr (for uint8_t*). Note you can also read from an IntPtr and copy where it points to a byte[] when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

It *should* get pinned, according to [Does .NET interop copy array data back and forth, or does it pin the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029593/does-net-interop-copy-array-data-back-and-forth-or-does-it-pin-the-array).

Though this doesn't seem really well documented or defined, so I'd pin it explicitly if I were you, to be safe.