# COM methods, Char type and CharSet

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, com, com-interop

This is a follow-up to my previous question: [Does .NET interop copy array data back and forth, or does it pin the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029593/does-net-interop-copy-array-data-back-and-force-or-pins-it)

My method is a COM interface method (rather than a `DllImport` method). The C# signature looks like this:

```
void Next(ref int pcch,
    [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)]
    char [] pchText);
```

MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tyybbf2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When a managed Char type, which has Unicode formatting by default, is
>   passed to unmanaged code, the interop marshaler converts the character
>   set to ANSI. You can apply the DllImportAttribute attribute to
>   platform invoke declarations and the StructLayoutAttribute attribute
>   to a COM interop declaration to control which character set a
>   marshaled Char type uses.

Also, @HansPassant in his answer [here says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25030068/2674222):

> A char[] can't be marshaled as LPWStr, it has to be LPArray. Now the
>   CharSet attribute plays a role, since you did not specify it, the
>   char[] will be marshaled as an 8-bit char[], not a 16-bit wchar_t[].
>   The marshaled array element is not the same size (it is not
>   "blittable") so the marshaller must copy the array.
>
> Pretty undesirable, particularly given that your C++ code expects
>   wchar_t. A very easy way to tell in this specific case is not getting
>   anything back in the array. If the array is marshaled by copying then
>   you have to tell the marshaller explicitly that the array needs to be
>   copied back after the call. You'd have to apply the [In, Out]
>   attribute on the argument. You'll get Chinese.

I coudn't find an analog of [`CharSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.charset%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (normally used with `DllImportAttribute` and `StructLayoutAttribute`) which could be applied to a COM interface method.

Nevertheless, I don't get "Chinese" on the output. Everything seems to work fine, I do get correct Unicode characters back from COM.

**Does it mean `Char` is always interpreted as `WCHAR` for COM method interop?**

I couldn't find any documentation confirming or denying this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a good question, and the `char` (`System.Char`) interop behavior does deserve some attention.

In managed code, `sizeof(char)` is always equal `2` (two bytes), because in .NET characters are always Unicode.

Nevertheless, the marshaling rules differ between cases when `char` for P/Invoke (calling an exported DLL API) and COM (calling a COM interface method).

**For P/Invoke**, [`CharSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.charset(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used explictly with any `[DllImport]` attribute, or implicitly via `[module|assembly: DefaultCharSet(CharSet.Auto|Ansi|Unicode)]`, to change the default setting for all `[DllImport]` declarations per module or per assembly.

The default value is `CharSet.Ansi`, which means there will be Unicode-to-ANSI conversion. I ussualy change the default to Unicode with `[module: DefaultCharSet(CharSet.Unicode)]`, and then selectively use `[DllImport(CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]` in those rare case where I need call an ANSI API.

It is also possible to alter any specific `char`-typed parameter with `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1|U2)` or `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1|U2)` (for a `char[]` parameter). E.g., you may have something like this:

```
[DllImport("Test.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern bool TestApi(
    int length,
    [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray] char[] buff1,
    [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray,
        ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)] char[] buff2);
```

In this case, `buff1` will be passed as an array of double-byte values (as is), but `buff2` will be converted to and from an array of single byte values. Note, this still will be a smart, Unicode-to-OS-current-code-page (and back) conversion for `buff2`. E.g, a Unicode '\x20AC' (`€`) will become `\x80` in the unmanaged code (rovided the OS code page is `Windows-1252`). This is how marshalling of `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)] char[] buff` would be different from `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)] ushort[] buff`. For `ushort`, `0x20AC` would be simply converted to `0xAC`.

**For calling a COM interface method**, the story is quite different. There, **`char` is always treated as a double-byte value representing a Unicode character**. Perhaps, the reason for such design decision could be implied from Don Box's "Essential COM" (quoting the footnote from [this page](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=kfRWvKSePmAC&lpg=PA74&ots=o8aWicbKdo&dq=OLECHAR%20type&pg=PA74#v=onepage&q=OLECHAR%20type&f=false)):

> The `OLECHAR` type was chosen in favor of the common `TCHAR` data type used by the Win32 API to alleviate the need to support two versions of each interface (`CHAR` and `WCHAR`). By supporting only one character type, object developers are decoupled from the state of the UNICODE preprocessor symbol used by their clients.

Apparently, the same concept made its way to .NET. I'm pretty confident this is true even for legacy ANSI platforms (like Windows 95, where `Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize == 1`).

Note that `DefaultCharSet` doesn't have any effect on `char` when it's a part of the COM interface method signature. Neither there is a way to apply `CharSet` explicitly. However, you still have full control over the marshaling behavior of each individual parameter with `MarshalAs`, in exactly the same way as for P/Invoke above. E.g., your `Next` method might look like below, in case the unmanaged COM code expects a buffer of ANSI characters:

```
void Next(ref int pcch,
    [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, 
        ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeParamIndex = 0)] char [] pchText);
```

Comment: With the non-matching `ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1`, .NET will make a temporary buffer where it will convert `char`s into `byte`s and back.  How did you determine the used charset, did you change the user's regional settings?

Comment: @PauloMadeira, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-system-locale. I didn't change it, `Windows-1252` is the default, where `€` is `\x80`.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping you were positively sure that changing the system, user or thread locale to e.g. to Windows-1251, € would yield \x88.  That is, that you were sure it doesn't use a hard-coded locale.

Comment: I'm 99% sure about that, despite I haven't tried it. Feel free to try and post an update if you like.

Comment: @PauloMadeira, I verified what Noseratio said. It indeed uses the system default locale, so Windows-1251 is not hard-coded.

Comment: @avo, now you confused me.  Did you try with 1252 and got \x80, and then with 1251 and got \x88?

Comment: @PauloMadeira, yes, that's exactly what I tried and what I got. \x88 in unmanaged code, and it was then correctly converted back to \x20AC upon return. I did the for the sake of trying, but I don't use `UnmanagedType.U1` anyway. I need Unicode on both sides.

Comment: @avo, thanks.  I got a chance to test it too with the same results, and indeed only the system locale affects it.  That is, the user locale and the thread locale don't affect it.  So, it's best to avoid the `char` to `I1` conversion anyway, it would be better to declare an array of `byte` and do the conversions manually around the call to get reliable and parameterizable Unicode↔8-bit translations.